# Failure when calling Dispatcher from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF MVVM application that runs some logic on a different thread and then when I want to do a UI update (hide the main window) I call the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` method and get the following error:

> "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject".

Any thoughts?

Edit:

The following code runs on a background thread (ignore the ugly code since this is just to demonstrate the issue):
In the `SomeWizardPage` constructor I'm creating a new instance of `BitmapImage` class and setting it into a property bound to the UI - this is what causes the failure. When I comment out the initialization of the image property from the constructor the the exception is not thrown.

```
Main.CurrentViewModel = new SomeWizardPage();
if (Main.MainWindow.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{

}
else
{
    Main.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
    {
        Main.MainWindow.Hide();
    }));
}
```

Can someone explain this behavior? How can I solve this?

Comment: is your window running on a different thread (i.e. a different Dispatcher) ?

Comment: @Dikla you need to show code that's causing the exception

Comment: I added additional information to my question - please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Is CurrentViewModel a DependencyProperty?

Comment: No, in the MainWindow.xaml.cs: DataContext = new MainViewModel();

Comment: -1 "I'm creating a new BitmapImage and setting it into a property binded to the UI" which you do not show at all in your code.

Answer (score 3):

`BitmapImage` is a `DependencyObject`. You cannot instantiate it from a background thread.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Nor should you ever need to if you are following MVVM. `BitmapImage` belongs in the View.

Comment: Thanks! I have a logic that determines which image will be display in the view depending on the current state. This logic sits in the view model. So how can I place the BitmapImage in the view with MVVM in such case?

Comment: @Dikla The `BitmapImage` should ALWAYS be in the `View` no exceptions. It is A UI element. It should be bound to the ViewModel. Do `<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ...}" />`. Have the binding bind to the ViewModel.

Comment: I've tried to bind the UriSource as you suggested to a property of type "Uri" in the view model, but the image is not displayed at run time. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Dikla Enable WPF binding errors in Visual Studio and look at the Output window. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx

Comment: @SergeyBrunov no part of your edit "Improved" my answer. Firstly your grammar was wrong. There is no "article" when describing the proper nouns of `BitmapImage` class nor `DependencyObject` class. You removed my reference. Plus you completely changed the intent of the last sentence.

Comment: @Aron, I am sorry for the edit if it is not okay for you. Just improved formatting and added "class" where appropriate, "is a" and "is derived from" are synonyms. By the way, the reference has not been removed (please see side-by-side markdown diff).